# How to convert ByteArray to Image in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*Image comes to as ByteArray from webservice.
 I want to convert it to image. How do we do that ?*

**image comes like this :**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us info on what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
var base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...';
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: base64Image}}/>
```

you can put `base64` data after `data:image/png;base64,`. As Shown below

```
var base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,{PLACE_YOUR_BASE64_DATA_HERE}';
```

Comment: I ran into some problems with this because of a quote (i.e. ") in my string. I removed that with imageString.replace(/['"]+/g, '') and then this worked for me.

Comment: you say 'place_your_base64_data_here', but he has a byte[], it doesn't work when placing the array their right? you have to convert it first?